# Css div overlapping is not occuring

Tags: html, css

i have tried to overlap the front and back div using the top function in css , it isnt working , what is the solution to this? These two are present within the cube div in the html code
bellow are the css and html code . Can you also tell what i wrote wrong . By overlapping i mean putting the 2 divs over each other

```css
:root {
  --boxColor: #0ff7
}

body {
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
  background-color: black;
  min-height: 100vh;
  font-size: 50px;
  perspective: 10px;
}

.scene {
  position: relative;
  transform-style: preserve-3d
}

.cube-container {
  perspective: 100px;
  perspective-origin: 50% 0%;
}

.cube {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

.front {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: blue;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.back {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: blue;
  opacity: 0.5;
  top: -100;
  position: absolute
}
```

```html
<div class="scene">
  <div class="cube-container">
    <div class="cube">
      <div class="front">
      </div>
      <div class="back">
      </div>
      <div class="top">
      </div>
      <div class="bottom">
      </div>
      <div class="left">
      </div>
      <div class="right">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you did not add the px in top , also you should try top 0px if position is absolute.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to fix this, but I'll go with the simplest one.

On your **.front** class in CSS, you also need to specific *position: absolute;*

This will allow both elements to position themselves the same way within the parent and should easily fix the issue you seem to be having.

```css
:root {
  --boxColor: #0ff7
}

body {
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
  background-color: black;
  min-height: 100vh;
  font-size: 50px;
  perspective: 10px;
}

.scene {
  position: relative;
  transform-style: preserve-3d
}

.cube-container {
  perspective: 100px;
  perspective-origin: 50% 0%;
}

.cube {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

.front {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: blue;
  opacity: 0.5;
  position: absolute
}

.back {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: blue;
  opacity: 0.5;
  position: absolute
}
```

```html
<div class="scene">
  <div class="cube-container">
    <div class="cube">
      <div class="front">
      </div>
      <div class="back">
      </div>
      <div class="top">
      </div>
      <div class="bottom">
      </div>
      <div class="left">
      </div>
      <div class="right">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just forgot the unit (vh) in back's top style. Try the following code:

```css
:root {
  --boxColor: #0ff7
}

body {
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
  background-color: black;
  min-height: 100vh;
  font-size: 50px;
  perspective: 10px;
}

.scene {
  position: relative;
  transform-style: preserve-3d
}

.cube-container {
  perspective: 100px;
  perspective-origin: 50% 0%;
}

.cube {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

.front {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: blue;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.back {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: blue;
  opacity: 0.5;
  top: -100vh;
  position: absolute
}
```

```html
<div class="scene">
  <div class="cube-container">
    <div class="cube">
      <div class="front">
      </div>
      <div class="back">
      </div>
      <div class="top">
      </div>
      <div class="bottom">
      </div>
      <div class="left">
      </div>
      <div class="right">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```